# Subtleties with LTSpice's Arbitrary Sources

Tags: current, capacitor-charging, thought-experiment

Here's my setup:

[image]

I'm trying to emulate the circuit to the right with the one on the left. That is, the one on the right is a pre-charged capacitor (node3) being discharged to its capacitor pair via a resistor (at this point, I'm asking about \$I_{max}\$ of the equation $$I(t) = I_{max} e^{-t/RC}$$.

The experiment on the left has the same setup, only it's an Arbitrary Behavioral Current Source, instead of a resistor, and it's not working as the one on the right.

What's wrong?

Comment: One is a resistor, the other a 5mA constant source. Doesn't seem to be equivalent. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Your title is as much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/#) as it can be. What you want is an emulated resistor, not a specific help about behavioural sources. Your expectations are also wrong: a resistor is not a current source. But if you want a resistor to be emulated by a current source then you need to apply Ohm's law: `I=V/R` -- currently, you discarded `V` and only used `R` (or an attempt at `1/R`). So, to correct the problem, you have to use `V` in the equation, and it can be done in two ways:

[image: emulated resistor]

`B1`'s expression is `V(a,b)/1k`, where `V(a,b)` is `V` and `1k` is `R` (considering `R1` from your circuit). `G1` is a 4-terminal element, whose two inputs are connected across the output, forming `V(a,c)`, which is the `V`. Its value is `1m` which is `1/1k`. The two behavioural sources below show the equivalent value of the two emulated resistors (green labels) -- they are 1 kΩ, both.